# Class App\Models\User not found in file Controllers\UserController.php

Tags: php, laravel

This is the error I am having:

> Class App\Models\User not found in file Controllers\UserController.php

`UserController` doesn't see `User` model.

This is `UserController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $status_code = 200;

    public function userSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->name;
        $name = explode(" ", $name);
        $first_name = $name[0];
        $last_name = "";

        $user_status = User::where("email", $request->email)->first(); // this is a problem line

        if (! is_null($user_status)) {
            return response()->json([
                "status" => "failed",
                "success" => false,
                "message" => "Whoops! email already registered"
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regenerate the autoload file with `composer dump-autoload -o` and try again. If it doesn't work paste/provide the exact error.

Comment: do you have a `User.php` file in `app/Models` and the namespace of that file is `App\Models` and the classname is `User`?

Answer (score 0):

Also this answer depends, on your version Laravel. Go to `config/auth.php` and check that you have `App\Models\User::class`.

```php
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

Also be sure the namespace of `User.php` model is

```php
namespace App\Models;
```

Additional work for this process help to clear cache

`php artisan config:cache`

`php artisan config:clear`